# XML Parse Error: Can't I Nest a RowActionItem in DynamicPage?

Tags: xml, sapui5

I use UI5 v1.52 and try to use `<rowActionTemplate>` within [sap.ui.TreeTable](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table/) nested in [sap.f.DynamicPage](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.f.DynamicPage). I wonder why I am getting an **XML parse error** making me guess I cannot use control RowAction(Item) in Dynamic Page?

```
<mvc:View
  controllerName="de.heliosit.zd.m.clinicalorder.commission.controller.OrderItems"
  xmlns="sap.f"
  xmlns:m="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:footerbar="sap.ushell.ui.footerbar"
  xmlns:tree="sap.ui.table"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
  <DynamicPage
    id="pageId"
    navButtonPress="onNavBack"
    showFooter="true">
    <header>
      <DynamicPageHeader />
    </header>
    <content>
      <tree:TreeTable
        id="orderItems"
        selectionMode="MultiToggle"
        enableColumnReordering="false"
        rowAction="1">
        <tree:columns>
          <tree:Column label="Name">
            <tree:template>
              <m:Text text="{Text}" wrapping="false" />
            </tree:template>
          </tree:Column>
          <tree:Column label="Catalog">
            <tree:template>
              <m:Text text="{CatalogId}" wrapping="false" />
            </tree:template>
          </tree:Column>
          </tree:Column>
        </tree:columns>
        <tree:rowActionTemplate>
          <tree:RowAction>
            <tree:RowActionItem
              type="Custom"
              icon="sap-icon://favorite"
              press="onManageFavoritePressed" />
            </tree:RowActionItem>
          </tree:RowAction>-->
        </tree:rowActionTemplate>
      </tree:TreeTable>
    </content>
    <footer>
      <m:OverflowToolbar>
        <m:ToolbarSpacer />
        <m:Button type="Accept" text="Accept" />
        <m:Button type="Reject" text="Reject" />
      </m:OverflowToolbar>
    </footer>
  </DynamicPage>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, there is nothing wrong with using DynamicPage together with TreeTable.
That being said, an XML parse error usually indicates that the document contains syntactical errors which is why it couldn't be parsed properly. Those errors were..

- Having the same closing tag twice

  > ```
  > </tree:Column>
  > </tree:Column>
  > ```
- Incomplete comment syntax

  > ```
  >   </tree:RowActionItem>
  > </tree:RowAction>-->
  > ```
- invalid property name `rowAction`

  > ```
  > rowAction="1"
  > ```

  It should be called `rowActionCount`.

Here is the same view without those errors:

```xml
<mvc:View
  controllerName="de.heliosit.zd.m.clinicalorder.commission.controller.OrderItems"
  xmlns="sap.f"
  xmlns:m="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:footerbar="sap.ushell.ui.footerbar"
  xmlns:tree="sap.ui.table"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
  <DynamicPage
    id="pageId"
    navButtonPress="onNavBack"
    showFooter="true">
    <header>
      <DynamicPageHeader />
    </header>
    <content>
      <tree:TreeTable 
        id="orderItems"
        selectionMode="MultiToggle"
        enableColumnReordering="false"
        rowActionCount="1">
        <tree:columns>
          <tree:Column label="Name">
            <tree:template>
              <m:Text text="{Text}" wrapping="false" />
            </tree:template>
          </tree:Column>
          <tree:Column label="Catalog">
            <tree:template>
              <m:Text text="{CatalogId}" wrapping="false" />
            </tree:template>
          </tree:Column>
        </tree:columns>
        <tree:rowActionTemplate>
          <tree:RowAction>
            <tree:RowActionItem
              type="Custom"
              icon="sap-icon://favorite"
              press="onManageFavoritePressed" />
          </tree:RowAction>
        </tree:rowActionTemplate>
      </tree:TreeTable>
    </content>
    <footer>
      <m:OverflowToolbar>
        <m:ToolbarSpacer />
        <m:Button type="Accept" text="Accept" />
        <m:Button type="Reject" text="Reject" />
      </m:OverflowToolbar>
    </footer>
  </DynamicPage>
</mvc:View>
```